# The consent message provided by Google updates each time when I refresh the page of my website

Tags: cmp, fundingchoices

The consent message provided by Google updates each time when I refresh the page of my website, for information I use the new code Google Publisher Tags.

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
```

I don't Know what can I do to fix this Problem.